# How to add lang::cpp:AST (Clair) to Rascal search path

Tags: rascal

After installing Clair onto Rascal 0.17.0

`import lang::cpp::AST;`

Gives the following error:

`Could not import module lang::cpp::AST: can not find in search path`

My Rascal project shows some search path entries, but not the Clair path.

Any suggestion as to how to make this work ?

Note that I tried installing Clair onto the latest version of Rascal (0.23), but that failed (so hence I used the older 0.17.0 version):

`Missing requirement: clair 0.2.0.202103011036 (clair 0.2.0.202103011036) requires 'osgi.bundle; rascal_eclipse [0.17.0,0.19.0)' but it could not be found`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need to add the following manually to your project.

in MANIFEST.MF -> Require-Bundle: rascal_eclipse, clair

in RASCAL.MF -> Require-Libraries: |lib://clair|

Comment: This indeed fixed the issue for me.